# OAuth PKCE code verifier is invalid 400 HTTP error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, authorization, http-status-code-400, etsy

I have a problem with OAuth authorization. I keep getting `400string(73) "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"code_verifier is invalid"} "` error.

My function to generate code verifier and code challenge:

```php
function GetOauthUrl(){
    $_SESSION["etsy_state"] = getRadomString(128);
    $txt = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < 32; $i++) {
        $txt .= chr(rand(0, 255));
    }    
    $txtEnc = base64_encode($txt);
    $code_challenge = str_replace('=', '', $txtEnc);
    $code_challenge = str_replace('+', '-', $code_challenge);
    $code_challenge = str_replace('/', '_', $code_challenge);

    $hashTxt = base64_encode(hash('sha256',$code_challenge));
    $hash = str_replace('=', '', $hashTxt);
    $hash = str_replace('+', '-', $hash);
    $hash = str_replace('/', '_', $hash);

    $url = "https://www.etsy.com/oauth/connect?response_type=code&client_id={$_SESSION['etsy_clientId']}&redirect_uri=$_SESSION['etsy_url']"
        ."&scope=listings_r%20listings_w%20listings_d&state={$_SESSION['etsy_state']}&code_challenge={$hash}&code_challenge_method=S256";

    $_SESSION["etsy_code_challenge"] = $code_challenge;
    return $url;
}
```

After retrieve auth code from API, I use function:

```php
function GetOauthToken(){
    $postfields = "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=".$_SESSION["etsy_clientId"]
        ."&redirect_uri=".$_SESSION['etsy_url']
        ."&code=".$_SESSION["etsy_authCode"]
        ."&code_verifier=".$_SESSION["etsy_code_challenge"];

    $url = "/v3/public/oauth/token";

    return PostHttpRequest($url, array('Cache-Control: no-cache'), $postfields);
}
```

Please help me.

I want to authorize by OAuth 2.0 in API, but I keep getting error:

```
400string(73) "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"code_verifier is invalid"} "
```

Comment: Not sure the code challenge is a standard bit of OAuth. Have you got a link to the API documentation where it describes what should be submitted for the code_verifier field?

Comment: FYI, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php exists. (And will take of applying possibly necessary URL encoding, in all the places where you have neglected it.)

Comment: @ADyson here you are, link to [Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://developer.etsy.com/documentation/essentials/authentication#proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce) in Etsy API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I think, by following the example given under https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#appendix-B - you need to base64-encode the *raw binary* output of the SHA-256 hash, not the lowercase hex-digit version.

```
$hashTxt = base64_encode(hash('sha256',$code_challenge,true));
                                                       ^^^^
```